# How can we club all the values for same key as a list and return Kafka Streams with key and value as String

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-interactive-queries

I have a data coming on kafka topic as (key:id, {id:1, body:...})
means key for the message is same as id. however there can be multiple messages with the same id but different body.
so I am getting the kstream `<String, String>`

Now I want to get all the messages having same id (key) and club all the values as a list and return as

```
Kstream<String, List<String>>
```

Any sugessions?

Comment: Why not serialize the value as a JsonArray? Otherwise, you need a `groupByKey` and `aggregate` call

Comment: Because JsonArray will consume my service's memory, and messages are coming from separate resources (multiple times as they can be executed). groupByKey is providing groupStream and by that I have to go for a ktable and once I m goong for a ktable it updates the values as single value.

Comment: By aggregating data at all, you need memory. Increase your heap, you'll be fine. You can customize the aggregate action of a table. It doesn't have to be a full replacement

Comment: I am going ahead with groupByKey and aggregate.

Comment: @Vivek can you share your solution?

Comment: I have used StatStore (Processor Implementation ) for this requirement, where Key(String) value (List). When I am getting the even I am verifying in the store if the key is present in the store then I am fetching the list and adding the value to that, otherwise I am creating a blank list and adding the value in the list and adding Key and list in the store. When we need to read from Rest layer I am getting the readonly instance of store and fetching the list based on Key and using it. But we need to take care that the list should not contain big values. and we might need to write custom Serdes

Comment: @Vivek were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes @SaurabhVerma the problem was solved as mentioned in the above statement. Let me share the code as well

Comment: yes sure. Please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //Create a Stream with a state store

    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, List<String>>> logTracerStateStore = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(LOG_TRACE_STATE_STORE), Serdes.String(),
            new ListSerde<String>(Serdes.String()));
            
    //add this to stream builder
    builder.addStateStore(logTracerStateStore);

    KStream<String, String> kafkaStream = builder.stream(TOPIC);
    splitProcessor(kafkaStream);
    logger.info("creating stream for topic {} ..", TOPIC);

    final Topology topology = builder.build();
    return new KafkaStreams(topology, streamConfiguration(bootstrapServers));
    

    // Stream List Serde 
    
    public class ListSerde<T> implements Serde<List<T>> {

         private final Serde<List<T>> inner;

          public ListSerde( final Serde<T> avroSerde) {
            inner = Serdes.serdeFrom(new ListSerializer<>( avroSerde.serializer()),
                                     new ListDeserializer<>( avroSerde.deserializer()));
          }

          @Override
          public Serializer<List<T>> serializer() {
            return inner.serializer();
          }

          @Override
          public Deserializer<List<T>> deserializer() {
            return inner.deserializer();
          }

          @Override
          public void configure(final Map<String, ?> configs, final boolean isKey) {
            inner.serializer().configure(configs, isKey);
            inner.deserializer().configure(configs, isKey);
          }

          @Override
          public void close() {
            inner.serializer().close();
            inner.deserializer().close();
          }
    }
    
    // Serializer & deserializers 
    
    public class ListSerializer<T> implements Serializer<List<T>> {

    //  private final Comparator<T> comparator;
      private final Serializer<T> valueSerializer;

      public ListSerializer( final Serializer<T> valueSerializer) {
    //      this.comparator = comparator;
          this.valueSerializer = valueSerializer;
      }
      @Override
      public void configure(final Map<String, ?> configs, final boolean isKey) {
          // do nothing
      }

      @Override
      public byte[] serialize(final String topic, final List<T> list) {
          final int size = list.size();
          final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          final DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos);
          final Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator();
          try {
              out.writeInt(size);
              while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                  final byte[] bytes = valueSerializer.serialize(topic, iterator.next());
                  out.writeInt(bytes.length);
                  out.write(bytes);
              }
              out.close();
          } catch (final IOException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException("unable to serialize List", e);
          }
          return baos.toByteArray();
      }

      @Override
      public void close() {

      }

    }
    
    //------------
    public class ListDeserializer<T> implements Deserializer<List<T>> {

    //  private final Comparator<T> comparator;
      private final Deserializer<T> valueDeserializer;

      public ListDeserializer(final Deserializer<T> valueDeserializer) {
    //      this.comparator = comparator;
          this.valueDeserializer = valueDeserializer;
      }

      @Override
      public void configure(final Map<String, ?> configs, final boolean isKey) {
          // do nothing
      }

      @Override
      public List<T> deserialize(final String s, final byte[] bytes) {
          if (bytes == null || bytes.length == 0) {
              return null;
          }
          final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
          final DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
          try {
              final int records = dataInputStream.readInt();
              for (int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
                  final byte[] valueBytes = new byte[dataInputStream.readInt()];
                  dataInputStream.read(valueBytes);
                  list.add(valueDeserializer.deserialize(s, valueBytes));
              }
    //          dataInputStream.close();
          } catch (final IOException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException("Unable to deserialize PriorityQueue", e);
          }finally {
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
          }
          return list;
      }

      @Override
      public void close() {

      }

    }
    /// Now create Stream Processors
    
    public class LogTraceStreamStateProcessor implements Processor<String, String>{

        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogTraceStreamStateProcessor.class);
        IStore stateStore;

        /**
         * Initialize the transformer.
         */
        @Override
        public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
            logger.info("initializing processor and looking for monitoring store");
            stateStore = MonitoringStateStoreFactory.getInstance().getStore();
            logger.debug("found the monitoring store - {} ", stateStore);
            stateStore.initLogTraceStoreProcess(context);
            logger.debug("initalizing monitoring store.");
        }

        @Override
        public void process(String key, String value) {

            logger.debug("Storing the value for logtrace storage - {} ", value);
            stateStore.storeLogTrace(value);
            logger.debug("finished Storing the value for logtrace storage - {} ", value);

        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
    
    // access the key value state store like below
    KeyValueStore<String, List<String>> stateStore =  (KeyValueStore<String, List<String>>) traceStreamContext.getStateStore(EXEID_REQ_REL_STORE);
    
    //Now add a list to new key for a new message and if the key exists then add a new message in the list
     
    public void storeTraceData(String traceData) {
        try {
            TraceEvent tracer = new TraceEvent();

            logger.debug("Received the Trace value - {}", traceData);
            tracer = mapper.readValue(traceData, TraceEvent.class);
            logger.debug("trace unmarshelling has been completed successfully !!!");

            String key = tracer.getExecutionId();
            
            List<String> listEvents = stateStore.get(key);

            if (listEvents != null && !listEvents.isEmpty()) {

                logger.debug("event is already in store so storing in the list for execution id - {}", key);
                listEvents.add(requestId);
                stateStore.put(key, listEvents);
            } else {
                logger.debug(
                        "event is not present in the store so creating a new list and adding into store for execution id - {}",
                        key);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(requestId);

                stateStore.put(key, list);

            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.error("exception while processing the trace event .. ", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                traceStreamContext.commit();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    /// now this is how you can access the message from state store
    public ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, List<String>> tracerStore() {
        return waitUntilStoreIsQueryable(KEY_NAME);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).